# Приведение generics типов в Java

Tags: java, list, generics

Задача сделать универсальный метод который выводит в консоль каждый элемент любого List с любым generic, почему не один вариант не компилируется ?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        List strs = Arrays.asList("abc", "zxc", "fgh");
        
        showList((ArrayList<Object>) nums);
        showList(List<Object> nums);
        showList((Object)strs);
    }

    static void showList(ArrayList<Object> list) {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static void showList(List<? extends Object> list) {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так как поставленной задачи нету, немного не понятно для чего вы хотите произвести такую конвертацию, для того чтобы просто печатать элементы вам достаточно оставить метод:

```
 static void showList(List<? extends Object> list) {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Или даже

```
 static void showList(List<?> list) {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

А вызывать его:

```
showList( nums);
showList( strs);
```

Для более точного понимания рекомендую почитать про wildcards и принцип PECS

Если же вы хотите конвертировать элементы списка из одного типа в другой, тогда воспользуйтесь `stream API` и метод `map`

Comment: мда, не зря говорят, СНГ комьюнити ужасное и беспощадное

Comment: Вот тоже возникло желание привязать к акк свои соцсети и ходить всем минусы раздавать просто так, без обьяснений